# Negative Moderator Message

Tags: discussion, status-completed

Moderator message for Questions with many answer is very negative (See an example [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/46716/what-should-a-developer-know-before-building-a-public-web-site)):

> With 75 answers it is highly unlikely that your answer will add anything new. Please feel free to comment or even edit existing answers if you wish to add extra information.

A better message could be a positive one:

> With 75 answers, it is highly *likely that an answer similar to yours was already posted*. Please feel free to comment or even edit existing answers if you wish to add extra information.

Answer (score 7):

This was fixed.

*(Posting an answer so someone can up-vote it causing it to drop off the unanswered list :P)*